# Setting JSDoc on properties that were added later

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, jsdoc

I am trying to add documentation on a property that was added later to an object in JavaScript code, but Visual Studio 2015 is not showing IntelliSense for it, probably I am doing it wrong.

```
/** @property {string} ID - A unique ID for student */
window.Data.Student.ID = null;
```

Note that `Data` and `Student` objects were initialized somewhere in the code, I cannot change that part. I am adding `ID` property later to `Student` object.